# Advantages from Java JDK over JRE

Tags: java, tomcat

Would someone be able to summarize all advantages from using Oracle Java JDK over JRE in a server environment (i.e. for Tomcat) for me? Using my prefered search engine I could only find fragments, which partially contradict themselves.

Comment: Do you need to run JSPs? Or compile code? Then you need a JDK.

Comment: See this related answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2277284/466738

Comment: We mainly run Tomcats serving war/jar-files. No development on our side! @AdamMichalik: Thanks for the link, but it does not talk about topics like GarbageCollector, etc. I am looking for...

Comment: @Joey Because there is nothing to talk about. JDK is simply the development kit that also includes a JRE, the running environment.

Comment: @biziclop: I think, this is not true. I learned in a Tomcat training that JDK can use "better" GarbageCollectors (like -XX:+UseParalleGC) next to being able to use memory > 1 GB compared to JRE. And I wonder, if more those advantages exist...

Comment: @Joey Well, either you misunderstood something or that Tomcat training was wrong. Maybe they were talking about server and client VMs? (Even then it isn't quite true though.)

Comment: @biziclop: I am very sure I misunderstood nothing related as I have 4 witnesses from my company sitting around me underlining what I was stating above ;-).

Comment: In that case the training was wrong. Why don't you just go ahead and try it? Get a clean machine, put a JRE and a Tomcat on it and see if you can use parallel GC. (For heaps above 2GB you'll need a 64 bit JRE.)

Comment: @biziclop: I currently cannot set this Tomcat up, which is why I was asking here ;-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My overall assessment of the situation is that what we get from these packages (JDK, JRE) is decided by the packaging team. To some extent, it is arbitrary. Let's see how, using the OpenJDK 7 packages on an Ubuntu system:

```
➜  ~  ls /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin
java  keytool  orbd  pack200  policytool  rmid  
rmiregistry  servertool  tnameserv  unpack200
➜  ~  ls /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin    
appletviewer  idlj       java     javah         jcmd      jhat   jps         
jstack  keytool       pack200     rmid         serialver   unpack200  
xjc apt           jar        javac    javap         jconsole  jinfo  
jrunscript  jstat   native2ascii  policytool  rmiregistry  servertool  
wsgen extcheck      jarsigner  javadoc  java-rmi.cgi  jdb       jmap   
jsadebugd   jstatd  orbd          rmic        schemagen    tnameserv    
wsimport
```

The first location is because of the package `openjdk-7-jre` (Java Runtime Environment), whereas the second location is because of `openjdk-7-jdk` (Java Development Kit) package. The `java` in second listing is actually a symbolic link to the `java` file from the first listing.

You can thus see what the JDK team thinks is the difference between the JRE and JDK is by comparing the programs (executables) that you get as part of these packages.

For a long long time, I have been rather confused by the choice of programs that are part of these packages. For instance, I have always missed the excellent serviceability tools like `jps`, `jstack`, and `jhat`, `jmap` when I installed only the JRE. These tools are *very* useful to diagnose a Java runtime and yet, they are *not* a part of the JRE. One has to, rather inexplicably, install the JDK in order to get these tools. Like others have pointed out, `javac`, the Java compiler definitely belongs to the JDK.

In general, I have come to the conclusion that one should install the JDK (the superset) and not the JRE on the target system, unless there are some space issues.

Comment: That is an answer how I love it :-).

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat has a bundled java compiler, so it works fine with just JRE. And less things you have on your server, the safer you are.

Comment: Thanks so far. Please see my comment above stating "I learned in a Tomcat training that JDK can use "better" GarbageCollectors (like -XX:+UseParalleGC) next to being able to use memory > 1 GB compared to JRE. And I wonder, if more those advantages exist..."